# Cannot Read Property of Undefined JQuery Option Tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting the error Cannot read property '####' of undefined (#### being any number I attempt to use)

The goal is to retrieve the inner html/text of my form options based on the number I provide. Here is an example of the text I am trying to retrieve using jQuery so I can send it with my form data.

```
<select>    
<option value="1">Sword</option> 
</select>
```

In this example, I am trying to retrieve the text -> "Sword"
This is based on the option value "1". This is how I attempt this:

```
$item       = $_POST['item'];
$option = "option[value='".$item."']";
```

$_POST['item'] returns the number (in this example, "1") to use to retrieve the inner text of the option with the given value.

The following is directly after the 2 lines above, it attempts to set the jQuery variable option.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var option = $(option[value="'.$item.'"]).html();</script>';
```

Lastly is the jQuery code, which uses the $option variable that was initialized earlier to attempt to retrieve the text inside the option ("Sword")

```
                            <script> 
                                console.log(option); 
                                var itemName = $(this.option).html();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data:{ itemName: itemName }, 
                                    success: function(data){
                                        console.log(itemName); 
                                    }
                                })
                            </script>
```

I know this code wouldn't work, because I am just using console.log to log the item name. However, my problem is that the console will log:

```
Cannot read property '1' of undefined.
```

Any advice? Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$(this.option)` makes no sense

Comment: Oops I was missing 1 line of the code, I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to access an option's text with jQuery is the following:

```
$('option[value="1"]').text()
```

This would return `Sword` in your example. The important difference is using `.text()` vs `.html()`.

Comment: No problem! Please accept the answer if it helped you out so that it might help out others in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access php variable using $(this.option).

Also appropriate way to do it would be :

```
$("#selectId option[value='1']").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectId option:eq(n)").text();
```

where n is the index of the option you want.